# How do I properly use `HTMLEditorKit.insertHTML()`?

Tags: java, html, swing

Here is my code.

`editPane` is a JEditorPane.
`HTMLKit` is a HTMLEditorKit assigned to `editPane`.

```
try
{
  HTMLKit.insertHTML(
  (HTMLDocument) editPane.getDocument(),
  editPane.getCaretPosition(),
  "test", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.B);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  exc.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(editPane.getText());
```

I started with the text [hello].
I expected to see the text [hello **test**].

However, the bold text was not inserted. How do I make it do what I want?

Comment: When asking a question post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String text = "<b>bold";
editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), text, 0, 0, null);
System.out.println( textPane.getText() );
```

or

```
String text = "<b>bold";
editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), text, 0, 0, HTML.Tag.B);
System.out.println( textPane.getText() );
```

The output from the text pane will show you what the difference is between using "null" or the HTML tag.

I don't really understand the functionality of the last 3 methods of the method.

Comment: It works with the `<b>` tag. I have now tried using something similar with the `<i>` tag. It simply inserts the text but not the tag, weirdly enough.